# How to enumerate local users and groups on a remote machine using RPC?

Tags: windows, rpc, privileges, system-administration, dcom

I'm trying to write a RPC client from scratch. My use case is enumerating local users and members of Built-in\Administrators group on a remote machine (Both machines are domain joined).

I know this case be done using PowerShell or perhaps with WMI.

But is there a RPC server exposed by default on a Windows 10 workstation that would allow enumerating local users and groups ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group  -ComputerName <PC>
```

Comment: Please provide context for your answer, including references to any documentation that would be helpful to the original question.